# Java nested if to switch statement

Tags: java, if-statement, nested, switch-statement

I'm having trouble transforming the following nested if statement below, into an equivalent switch statement. If anyone can give me some advice, it would be appreciated.

```
if (num1 == 5)
    myChar = ‘A’;
else
if (num1 == 6 )
    myChar = ‘B’;
else
if (num1 = 7)
    myChar = ‘C’;
else
    myChar = ‘D’;
```

Comment: Please show any attempt at a `switch` statement you've made, along with any problems you've encountered.

Comment: [`java switch statement docs`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

Comment: Note:  These `if` blocks are not *nested*.  They are ***chained***.

Comment: For something like this he could also use a character array over a switch statement. `char [] chars = {'A','B','C','D'}; int index = num1-5; myChar = chars[index];`

Answer (score 2):

Pretty straightforward, just use the number as the thing you want to switch on. Your `else` case becomes the `default` case.

```
switch (num1) {
    case 5:
        myChar = 'A';
        break;
    case 6:
        myChar = 'B';
        break;
    case 7:
        myChar = 'C';
        break;
    default:
        myChar = 'D';
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For more details chek the documentation : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

```
switch(num1){
 case 5:
   myChar = ‘A’;
   break;
 case 6:
   myChar = ‘B’;
   break;
 case 7:
   myChar = ‘C’;
   break;
 default:
   myChar = ‘D’;
}
```

Comment: This would return either A or D only. You should change the values of your case statements.

Answer (score 1):

If the values follow a simple pattern like this, you don't need a `switch` at all. For example you can do

```
myChar = num1 >= 5 && num1 <= 7 ? (char) ('A' + num1 - 5) : 'D';
```

If `num1` is always `5`, `6`, `7` or `8` you can just do

```
myChar = (char) ('A' + num1 - 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

In JDK 12, extended switch will allow you to assign a char value directly to the switch. Construct your switch as such:

```
char myChar = switch(num1) {
    case 5 -> 'A';
    case 6 -> 'B'; 
    case 7 -> 'C';
    default -> 'D';
}
```

Comment: It's good that you showcase a fairly new feature in Java, but I think it'd be worth to also add an example for pre-java 12.